# Should pytest.main('-s') run tests twice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I've only just started learning about testing, and so I'm just starting out by trying to put together and run some very simple unit tests using py.test.

Example `test_script.py`:

```
import pytest

def test_func():
    assert True

pytest.main('-v')
```

Running this gives:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.3.1 -- pytest-2.3.4 -- C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\python.exe
collecting ... collected 1 items

test_script.py:3: test_func PASSED
=========================== 1 passed in 0.12 seconds ===========================
```

If I replace `-v` with `-s` to view stdout (and disable pytest capturing of stdout), the tests run twice:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.3.1 -- pytest-2.3.4
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.3.1 -- pytest-2.3.4
collected 1 items

test_script.py .

=========================== 1 passed in 0.04 seconds ===========================
collected 1 items

test_script.py .

=========================== 1 passed in 0.12 seconds ===========================
```

Should the tests run twice here? I did search, but couldn't find anything obvious in the documentation (though may have been looking in the wrong place).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a funny one :)

here is what happens: python executes test_script.py and thus executes `pytest.main("-s")` which goes back to the file system and collects the `test_script.py` as a test module.  When pytest imports `test_script`, `pytest.main(...)` is invoked again during collection. The second invocation does not import `test_script` again because that is in `sys.modules` now, but it executes the test function.  When the collection has finished (and the inner pytest.main run has executed the test once), the test function is also executed by the outer pytest.main invocation.  Everything clear?  :)

If you want to avoid this, you need to wrap the pytest.main invocation like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main("-s")
```

This invocation will not execute on a normal import but it will execute when you issue `python test_script.py` because python executes a command line specified script by setting `__name__` to `__main__` but to `test_script` upon a normal `import test_script` import.

Answer (score 0):

hpk42 gave the correct reasoning above in his answer. For me the solution is to simply rename test_script.py (in my case unit_test.py) to unit.py. Since PyTest only detects file names like test_*.py or *_test.py.